# Let $f$ be from the reals to the reals, such that $f'(x)<x$, and let $h(x)=f(x)-\frac{x^2}{2}$, prove or disprove: $h(x)$ has exactly one root

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ be from the reals to the reals, such that $f'(x)<x$, and let $h(x)=f(x)-\frac{x^2}{2}$, prove or disprove: $h(x)$ has exactly one root.

I'm quite sure I need to disprove this. Since the derivative of $h(x)$ is less than zero, it only means that $h(x)$ can only have at most one root, but it doesn't mean it has exactly one root, but I can't find a function that will disprove this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument showing that there is atmost one root is correct. To show that there need not be any root consider $f(x)=\frac {x^{2}} 2+e^{-x}$.